# PHP Contact Form not working - not sending messages

Tags: php, html

I have never used PHP before so apologies if this is totally ridiculous. I am struggling to get my contact form to work. Here is my HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="contact-form.php">

            <div class="input-third">

                <label for="name">Name: <small>*</small></label>
                <br>
                <input class="input"  type="text" name="name" placeholder="John Smith" />

            </div>

            <div class="input-third">

                <label for="email">Email: <small>*</small></label>
                <br>
                <input class="input"  type="text" name="email" placeholder="mail@example.com" />

            </div>

            <div class="input-third">

                <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
                <br>
                <input class="input"  type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Type Here" />

            </div>

            <br>
            <br>

            <label for="message">Message: <small>*</small></label> <br>
            <textarea class="message" name="message" placeholder="Write a message to us"></textarea>

            <br>

            <label>*What is 2+2? (Anti-spam)</label>
            <input name="human" placeholder="Type Here">

            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Send" name="submit">

        </form>
```

And Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: IPS Facilities Contact Form';
$to = 'noah.searle@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Enquiry';
$human = $_POST['human'];

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message: $message\n";

if ($_POST['submit'] && $human == '4') {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
    }
} else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
    echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
}
?>
```

When I hit submit, it displays the message has been sent but I have not received anything! I'm sure it is something silly but I would appreciate some input!

Comment: `$message = $_POST['message'];` you are missing semicolon?

Comment: `mail(to, subject, message` missing `$`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: also, `mail($to, $subject, $message, $from)`

Answer (score 1):

Think this may have already been answered in the comments or other answers, but thought that I would just add this for your reference and also for any future readers.

If you are having an error 500, it means there is an error in your php code. You can set error reporting to 'on' in your php by adding the following to the top of your php file:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

If you add that, then reload the front end you should get some more details about the error and it may help you decipher the problem and fix it.

Comment: This is really helpful thank you. However I am still not receiving the messages. From the other comments I realised I had missed a semi colon. I get the "Message sent" feedback but nothing received.

Answer (score 0):

$message = $_POST['message']  // you miss ;

Answer (score 0):

Missing semicolon on $message = $_POST['message'] and your mail function is missing dollar signs against the variables.

Answer (score 0):

you have missed a semicolon here in **$message = $_POST['message']**
also you missed a $ sign here **if (mail(to, subject, message, from))**

and make sure your php file name is **contact-form.php**

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected these errors but still receiving no message. Any ideas?

Comment: make sure wamp is installed properly and you are opening the html and php files via localhost

Comment: I am not running on Wamp, it is already a live site hosted on an external server.